# How does Numpy import its `numpy.core` package?

Tags: python, python-import

I was trying to understand how packages like Numpy/Pandas makes its imports, and Numpy seems to call from its core package. For example, in `numpy/linalg/linalg.py`, it makes an import

```py
from numpy.core import (
    array, asarray, zeros, empty, empty_like, intc, single, double,
    csingle, cdouble, inexact, complexfloating, newaxis, all, Inf, dot,
    add, multiply, sqrt, fastCopyAndTranspose, sum, isfinite,
    finfo, errstate, geterrobj, moveaxis, amin, amax, product, abs,
    atleast_2d, intp, asanyarray, object_, matmul,
    swapaxes, divide, count_nonzero, isnan, sign
)
```

in order to make its basic operations. However, the folder structure is

```
numpy
   > core
       > __init__.py
       > _asarray.py
       > _dtype.py
       ... 
   > linalg
       > __init__.py
       > linalg.py      <--- Looking at this one
       ...
   > fft 
       > __init__.py
       > helper.py
       > _pocketfft.py  <--- Same thing happens here
       ...
```

But since `core` is a sister directory to `linalg`, how is it that `numpy/linalg/linalg.py` is able to use `from numpy.core import ...` since it wouldn't be able to capture anything from a parent directory?

My problem is that I have a folder structure:

```
pkg
   > banana
       > __init__.py
       > banana.py
   > fruit
       > __init__.py
       > fruit.py
```

where

```py
# pkg/fruit/__init__.py
from .fruit import func1
```

```py
# pkg/banana/__init__.py
from .banana import *
from ..fruit import func1 # This won't work
```

and I'd like to have `func1` be used in the `banana` package

Answer (score 2):

`from numpy.core import ...` is an absolute import. The import mechanism looks for `numpy` in one of the directories listed in `sys.path`, not the directory where the current file is stored.

I suspect your problem is that `pkg.__init__.py` doesn't exist, meaning `pkg` is simply a directory, not a Python package.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be how you are running it. I've solved similar problems by going to the directory above pkg and running `python -m pkg.banana.__init__`.

Here's question that has a lot of good information. [Python Relative Imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Answer (score 0):

Use an absolute import: `from pkg.fruit import func1`. As @chepner points out, this is what the import in numpy is doing.

If you are using python 2 then `pkg/__init__.py` must exist, but this requirement no longer exists in python 3.